# On Ubuntu - Problem with default application on opening php file

Tags: ubuntu-20.04

I just installed ubuntu 20.04, and I removed gedit. I configured the default application of php file to be opened with sublime text.
Problem : when I click on a *.php file. It opens chrome. Worst : even when I click on "open with sublime text", it opens chrome !
I configured my ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list :

```
[Default Applications]
text/php=sublime_text.desktop
text/x-php=sublime_text.desktop
application/php=sublime_text.desktop
application/x-php=sublime_text.desktop
application/x-httpd-php=sublime_text.desktop
application/x-httpd-php-source=sublime_text.desktop
```

But it changes nothing.
Any idea ?

Comment: maybe you have `mimeapps.list` in different location ? mine is on `/home/user/.config/mimeapps.list` . And it follows changes.